# Why embedding webpages doesn't work for all sites

Tags: html

I use code like this to embed webpage within a webpage:

```
<object data="http://www.cnn.com" type="text/html">
    <embed src="http://www.cnn.com" type="text/html" />
</object>
```

For some sites this works, but for some it doesn't - it doesn't show anything. Why? It there something that can be fixed with the code or is it better to embed sites in some different way?

Here is example of site that works and site that doesn't work:
http://jsfiddle.net/fqpfj1th/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to the `X-Frame-Options` header being present:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:9459
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 10 May 2015 13:51:36 GMT
ETag:"1431265860-0"
Expires:Sun, 10 May 2015 13:51:36 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 10 May 2015 13:51:00 GMT
Link:; rel="canonical",; rel="shortlink"
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Drupal-Cache:MISS
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator:Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
X-Server:web05a.sjc05.teslamotors.com
X-Varnish:1302280716
X-Varnish-Server:varnish02a.sjc05.teslamotors.com
```

This is a non-standard header that is superseded by the CSP Level 2 spec, but has better support across browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Yes, that's it. I will check if url has it and show adequate mssg about it. Thanks.